# css and images are not loaded on IIS

Tags: css, asp.net, iis, iis-6

This is my web config

```
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
        <add name="vmpcon" connectionString="data source=localhost;Database=XXXX;User ID=XXXX;Password=XXXX; Trusted_Connection=False;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
    </connectionStrings>
    <system.web>
      <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
      <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
    </system.web>

</configuration>
```

I have one page on that site, and when I navigate to it, I got just the html without any css affects and without the images.

I tried using chrome to check if there is any error on console but there is no error on console

I choose `integrated` on IIS, but If i choose `classic`, the page becomes empty.

help me to load the css and images please?

if you need more information tell me please

`IIS 6.1`

#### Update 1

In chrome, I see that the type of the css file is `text/plain` though I declare it like this:

```
<head runat="server">
    <title>YMC Popup</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css"/>
</head>
```

Comment: No 404 errors at all no? The resources just simply not requested?

Comment: @DeeMac there is no 404 error,

Comment: Check the network tab and tell us whether any requests have been made for the CSS or images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enabling static content via server manager was the solution